# How Do I Position & Size the Output in a Manipulate Panel in Mathematica?

Tags: user-interface, wolfram-mathematica

The following code allows you to play with the values in a Wheatstone Bridge. The output appears to the right of the sliders. How do I make the output panel (*expr*) appear somewhere else and how do I set a fixed size? (I can only find options for manipulating size and position of Controls, not the output in the Manipulate docs.)

```
Manipulate[
 Evaluate[(10^Rx/(10^R3 + 10^Rx) - 10^R2/(10^R1 + 10^R2))*Vin] "V",
 {{R1, 5}, 1, 6, 0.01},
 Pane["R1  = " Dynamic[Round[10^R1] "\[CapitalOmega]"], 
  ImageMargins -> {{2.5, 0}, {3, 0}}], {{R2, 5}, 1, 6, 0.01},
 Pane["R2  = " Dynamic[Round[10^R2] "\[CapitalOmega]"], 
  ImageMargins -> {{2.5, 0}, {3, 0}}], {{R3, 5}, 1, 6, 0.01},
 Pane["R3  = " Dynamic[Round[10^R3] "\[CapitalOmega]"], 
  ImageMargins -> {{2.5, 0}, {3, 0}}],
 {{Rx, 5}, 1, 6, 0.01},
 Pane["Rx  = " Dynamic[Round[10^Rx] "\[CapitalOmega]"], 
  ImageMargins -> {{2.5, 0}, {3, 0}}],
 {{Vin, 2.5}, 0, VMax, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you can position the controls with respect to the content box then you're positioning the content box wrt the controls as well, aren't you?

So, `ControlPlacement` should take care of the position of your box, and putting it in a `Pane` takes care of sizing it (with `ImageSize`, although it seems that it takes its minimum size from the control sizes).

```
VMax = 12;
Manipulate[
 Pane[ToString[(10^Rx/(10^R3 + 10^Rx) - 10^R2/(10^R1 + 10^R2))*Vin] <> 
   "V", ImageSize -> {500, 20}], {{R1, 5}, 1, 6, 0.01}, 
 Pane["R1  = " Dynamic[Round[10^R1] "\[CapitalOmega]"], 
  ImageMargins -> {{2.5, 0}, {3, 0}}], {{R2, 5}, 1, 6, 0.01}, 
 Pane["R2  = " Dynamic[Round[10^R2] "\[CapitalOmega]"], 
  ImageMargins -> {{2.5, 0}, {3, 0}}], {{R3, 5}, 1, 6, 0.01}, 
 Pane["R3  = " Dynamic[Round[10^R3] "\[CapitalOmega]"], 
  ImageMargins -> {{2.5, 0}, {3, 0}}], {{Rx, 5}, 1, 6, 0.01}, 
 Pane["Rx  = " Dynamic[Round[10^Rx] "\[CapitalOmega]"], 
  ImageMargins -> {{2.5, 0}, {3, 0}}], {{Vin, 2.5}, 0, VMax, 
  Appearance -> "Open"}, ControlPlacement -> Bottom]
```

[image]

**EDIT** Changed `[CapitalOmega]` to `\[CapitalOmega]`. Thanks Belisarius.

New picture. Thanks Wizard.

Comment: I checked my map and it is `\[CapitalAthenas]`  :D

Comment: @Sjoerd The backslashes tend to disappear from the code blocks. That was what happened to the OP.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Been playing with too many different versions. Replaced figure with correct one.

Comment: @belisarius  So I noticed. Any failsafe way to prevent it?